# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of null - WordPress Dashboard Not Loading

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Hello fellow developers and problem-solvers,

I have come across an issue after logging into this WordPress website. This appears to be happening on the main Dashboard page the plugins page and many other pages.

From doing some Google searches of the console error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 
   'action' of null
        at load-scripts.php:20
        at dispatch (load-scripts.php:3)
        at r.handle (load-scripts.php:3)`

I found some other Stack Overflow questions related to the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of null". But not specific to this case with the WordPress Dashboard.

I am fairly new to trouble-shooting console errors especially involving core WordPress files.

[image: WordPress Dashboard Not Loading]

[image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of null at load-scripts.php:20 at dispatch (load-scripts.php:3) at r.handle (load-scripts.php:3)]

> **load-scripts.php**

https://website.com/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,wp-util,wp-a11y,updates&ver=4.6.12

Any help would be greatly appreciated on solving this issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you tried deactivating the plugin  "My WP Plugin"?

Comment: @charankumar thank you very much, I didn't think that would be the issue but it fixed it.

Comment: Do not post screenshot of codes. Copy & paste your codes in your question please.

Comment: @Raptor - thank you very much. I removed the last image and will do that in the future. I'm always looking to improve on how I post questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin "My WP Plugin" might be creating the problem, Try to deactivate it.